Exclusions from Blazor SSR parameterised pages
I have a Blazor SSR page with a simple domainname/{urlparam} page route, the urlparam is then used to dynamically show different page content; I can't change the URL pattern. It works fine but I've added Google Adsense and need to add an ads.txt file in the root, however this is being picked up by the page route as a urlparam for the page so the actual file can't be found.
Ideally I'd like to specify an exclusion criteria for the page to exclude ads.txt but can't work out how to do that, does anyone know how I can still allow the ads.txt file to load?
Edit:
Thanks @Qiang-Fu but I get:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'EndpointRoutingMiddleware matches
endpoints setup by EndpointMiddleware and so must be added to the
request execution pipeline before EndpointMiddleware. Please add
EndpointRoutingMiddleware by calling 'IApplicationBuilder.UseRouting'
inside the call to 'Configure(...)' in the application startup code.'

This is my program.cs:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyComponents();

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery();

app.UseWhen(context => !context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/ads.txt"), //determine if not start with "/ads.txt" 
    appBuilder =>
    {
        appBuilder.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorComponents<App>();
        });

    });

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode()
    .AddAdditionalAssemblies(typeof(TestProject.Client._Imports).Assembly);

app.Run();


You could conditionally map the blazor route to achieve this. Just note that the middleware order is important and should be like following:
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAntiforgery();
app.UseWhen(context => !context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/ads.txt"), //determine if not start with "/ads.txt" 
    appBuilder =>
    {
        appBuilder.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorComponents<App>();          
        });

    });
app.Run();


Thanks, I applied the change but got the error you thought might happen, I've updated my question with details

@dnky These middlewares are necessary and the order is important. It has to be UseStaticFiles ->UseRouting -> UseAntiforgery -> UseWhen. Generally UseRouing is used implicit. But you need to explicit use it here to make an order.

Yep that's it, it's now working properly - thanks so much.

@dnky Glad to hear that. Would you help to follow the instruction:) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.
